# Printing matplot graph in django?

Tags: python, django

> Views.py:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from tweetanalysis import tweety
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import base64
from io import BytesIO
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index-search.html')


def result(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.POST.get('hashtage')
        df = tweety.Analyzer(query)
        plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
        for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
            plt.scatter(df.loc[i, 'Polarity'],
                        df.loc[i, 'Subjectivity'], color='Blue')

        plt.title('Sentiment Analysis')
        plt.xlabel('Polarity')
        plt.ylabel('Subjectivity')
        buffer = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(buffer, format='png')
        buffer.seek(0)
        image_png = buffer.getvalue()
        ans1 = base64.b64encode(image_png)
        ans1 = ans1.decode('utf-8')
        buffer.close()

        plt.title('Sentiment Analysis')
        plt.xlabel('Polarity')
        plt.ylabel('Subjectivity')
        df['Analysis'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
        buffer = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(buffer, format='png')
        buffer.seek(0)
        image_png = buffer.getvalue()
        ans2 = base64.b64encode(image_png)
        ans2 = ans2.decode('utf-8')
        buffer.close()
        return render(request, 'result.html', {'chart': ans1, 'plot': ans2})
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Error!")
```

> result.html:-

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %} 
    {% if chart %}
        <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{chart|safe}}" />
    {% endif %}
<br />
    {% if plot %}
        <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{plot|safe}}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

> here df in dataframe. I am making a tweet sentiment analysis web app
> For that I want to print my matplot graphs in frontend as a result in django but error arises **name 'posts' is not defined**. Here in my code my sentiment analysis code return dataframe contains tweets polarity subjectivity. I want to show scatter graph and bar plot.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Name error comes when ever I add something. NameError at /result.html
name 'posts' is not defined
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/result.html
Django Version: 3.2.9
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value: 
name 'posts' is not defined
Exception Location: D:\Projects\Tweet Sentiment Analysis webapp\sentianalysis\tweetanalysis\tweety.py, line 28, in Analyzer
Python Executable: D:\Pyhton39\python.exe

Comment: The error originates from the `tweety.py` module, not the views file...